# Two 2d-arrays defined in main function make C program do nothing

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, cmake

I either found a very weird bug, or I am doing something wrong.

I am using Visual Studio Code v1.62.3 with CMakeTools v1.9.2

Here's my project structure:

```
clab
│   CMakeLists.txt
│
└───src
        not_a_test.c
```

And contents of `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(clab)

add_executable(not_a_test src/not_a_test.c)
```

The kit I'm using is
[image: kit]

So here's the strange part. If the contents of `not_a_test.c` are

```c
#include <stdio.h> 

#define MAX_ARR_SIZE 500

int main(void) {
    int mat[MAX_ARR_SIZE][MAX_ARR_SIZE];

    printf("Hello!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

It runs absolutely normally.
[image: The normal run]

But if I add one line

```c
#include <stdio.h> 

#define MAX_ARR_SIZE 500

int main(void) {
    int mat[MAX_ARR_SIZE][MAX_ARR_SIZE];
    int mat2[MAX_ARR_SIZE][MAX_ARR_SIZE]; // this one

    printf("Hello!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

It suddenly stops working at all
[image: It stopped working]

Also, when compiled via ideone / GCC v8.3 it works fine again: https://ideone.com/Vvrnnn
[image: ideone]

So, what do you think happens here?

Comment: first thing: Never call your program `test.exe`, most likely the OS has a command `test`, declare the arrays outside function, maybe your stack is not big enough

Comment: I don't think it affects anything at all, but if you think so, I'll rename it.

Comment: have you tried my other suggestion

Comment: No, because it wasn't there when I saw the comment. I'll try it now.

Comment: I never remember the exact stack sizes used by Windows or Linux but I believe it's somewhere around 1Mb. Your array blows up about that much memory, so you get a stack overflow.

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/f-set-stack-size?view=msvc-170), MSVC defaults to a stack size of 1 MB. Use the `/F number` compiler option or the `/STACK:reserve,commit` linker option to change the stack size.